# Is there any documentation tool available for GraphQl?

Tags: magento2.3.4, graphql, documentation, tools

I need to document both Magento2 in-built and custom GraphQl endpoints. (Just like we use swagger to document APIs). So far I tried the below tools. But both seem to be covering a limited number of GraphQl endpoints. They do not generate documentation for all the GraphQl endpoints available in Magento.

- https://github.com/APIs-guru/graphql-voyager
- https://github.com/2fd/graphdoc#readme

It would be great if you can share any tool which you have used to document GraphQl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use **Altair** tool in your **Chrome** browser to download all magento default as well as your custom GraphQL endpoints.

[image]

You can use "**Export SDL**" option in order to download the specific query or mutation documentation.

I hope this helps!

Thanks,

Comment: Thank you so much and +1.  It does the work